# ¿Cómo mantener "activado" el buscador SearcView al entrar a una Activity?

Tags: android

Necesito saber como puedo mantener activado el ***SearchView*** al ingresar a una activity, ahora solo conseguí que me muestre la "LUPA", presiono sobre ella y el buscador se "expande" a la derecha del toolbar. Necesito que esa lupa se mantenga activada cuando ingrese a la activity. Acá les dejo mi código tanto del **menu.xml** como el de la activity:

**menu.buscar_cliente_para_realizar_venta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/hint_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />



</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.prueba_de_modulos;

import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;  
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class BuscarClienteParaRealizarVenta extends AppCompatActivity  
implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buscar_cliente_para_realizar_venta);



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_buscar_cliente_para_realizar_venta, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) 
    MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    // User pressed the search button
    return false;

}

@Override

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    // User changed the text
    return false;

}

}
```

Espero su ayuda! muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Reemplaza esta sección del codigo:

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

SearchView searchView = (SearchView) 
MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
```

y agrega la siguiente linea de código en tu metodo `onCreateOptionsMenu()`:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
searchItem.expandActionView();
```

Por favor, antes de publicar una pregunta en Stack Overflow, primero realiza una búsqueda, para ver si ya existe una respuesta. Puedes encontrar una respuesta aquí [How to make SearchView always expanded in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122448/how-to-make-searchview-always-expanded-in-android)